# What to destroy with unfollow feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a follow/unfollow feature in my rails/angular app following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users guide. But when I want to unfollow a friend the method removes the id of the user.

The removeFollower function in my template,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "follower in followers"}
  %li
    {{ follower.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "removeFollower(follower)"} Remove
```

The removeFollower function in my controller,

```
$scope.removeFollower = function(follower){
  console.log (follower)
  console.log (follower.name)
  removeFollower.removeFollower(follower).then(function(){
  },function(){
  }).then(init);
  Notification.success(follower.name + ' is verwijderd als vriend.');
}
```

And the removeFollower service,

```
app.factory('removeFollower', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    removeFollower: function(follower) {
      var follower_id =  parseInt(follower.id);
      var follower_name =  (follower.name)
      console.log (follower_id)
      return $http.delete('/relationships/'+follower_id + '.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

And the destroy method in my relationship_controller,

```
def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow(@user)
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

So when I unfollow a user the method removes the wrong object (I think).

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Relationship with 'id'=3):
>     app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:13:in `destroy'

The id here is the user id of the user I'm trying to unfollow and I think it should be the id of the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the `follower_id` in you `delete` request `$http.delete('/relationships/'+follower_id + '.json');` so you have one of two options.

1. Your `@user` should not be an instance of a `Relationship` but rather an instance of `User` model

   ```
    def destroy
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      current_user.unfollow(@user)
      redirect_to root_url
    end
   ```

And your `unfollow(user)` method should destroy a `Relationship` instance that is `Relationship.where(follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user.id).destroy`

2. Or send the `follower` id to the controller directly and change your destroy method to:

   ```
    def destroy
      current_user.relationships.where(follower_id: params[:id]).destroy_all
      redirect_to root_url
    end
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was kind of tunnelviewed, your first suggestion worked fine, so question resolved. But for full disclosure the second suggestion gave me a `NoMethodError (undefined method `relationships' for #<User:0x007efea47dc6d0>):
  app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:13:in `destroy'
` error.

Comment: You have to create a has_many association between user and relationships

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you for explaining. And thank you for providing a good solution.